# Why doesn't pselect adjust the timeout argument?

Tags: select, posix, posix-select

The manual page for `select`/`pselect` [1] along with this LWN article [2] explicitly mention that calls to the library function `pselect` will not modify the timeout argument whereas the `select` call might, depending on the implementation. The LWN article mentions that the system call `pselect` does modify the timeout, and the library function is hiding that from the caller.

Why was the library method `pselect` specified to not modify the timeout parameter? It seems like a useful feature to know if a timed method returned with time to spare.

For example, I'd like to wait up to some timespec for X bytes to be received. I could implement a loop that calls `pselect` to wait for data, accumulates any data read, accumulates time spent waiting, and then decides whether to loop again depending on whether enough bytes were read or enough time has elapsed. Since `pselect` doesn't modify the timeout parameter with the remaining time, I would have to call `gettimeofday` to calculate the remaining time window.

[1] http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html

[2] https://lwn.net/Articles/176911/

Comment: I'm not very sure any answers you will get is going to be of any use. The man page states the reason as well, it is to be compliant with posix (select() on linux isn't posix compliant, but it was added to linux early on and changing it would break many applications.)

Comment: @nos The SUS as far back as at least version 2 says that select may modify the timeout argument. I can see why that unreliability could cause problems. I'm just curious why then pselect was drafted to MUST NOT rather than MUST. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/select.html